# Grep logs between two timestamps in Shell

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, grep

I am writing a script where I need to grep the logs exactly between two given timestamps . I don't want to use regex as it not full proof. Is there any other way through which I can achieve this ?

e.g: between time range 04:15:00 to 05:15:00

## Log Format:

```
170.37.144.10 - - [17/Dec/2015:04:00:00 -0500] "GET /abc/def/ghi/xyz.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 337 3440 0000FqZTmTG2yuMTJeny7hPDOvG
170.37.144.10 - - [17/Dec/2015:05:10:09 -0500] "POST /abc/def/ghi/xyz.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 27 21124 0000FqZTmTG2yuMTJ
```

Comment: Use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: Edit your sample input to provide a few lines of sample input that includes lines you want to find, similar lines you don't want to find, and the lines you want output and lines you don't want output. Then add the expected output given that input. Include timestamps that cross day boundaries but where the same time of day exists in both days. Also clarify if you want to find start/end timestamps that are = the provided timestamps or >= start and <= end, e.g. if you want to print between 8am and 10am but neither exact timestamp exists do you still want to print the lines between those times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use regular expressions nor patterns for matching lines, then grep alone is not enough.

Here's a Bash+date solution:

```
# start and stop may be parameters of your script ("$1" and "$2"),
# here they are hardcoded for convenience.
start="17/Dec/2015 04:15:00 -0500"
stop="17/Dec/2015 05:15:00 -0500"

get_tstamp() {
    # '17/Dec/2015:05:10:09 -0500' -> '17/Dec/2015 05:10:09 -0500'
    datetime="${1/:/ }"
    # '17/Dec/2015 05:10:09 -0500' -> '17 Dec 2015 05:10:09 -0500'
    datetime="${datetime//// }"

    # datetime to unix timestamp
    date -d "$datetime" '+%s'
}

start=$(get_tstamp "$start")
stop=$(get_tstamp "$stop")

while read -r line
do
    datetime="${line%%:*}" # remove ':170.37.144.10 ...'
    tstamp="$(get_tstamp "$datetime")"

    # $tstamp now contains a number like 1450347009;
    # check if it is in range $start..$stop
    [[ "$tstamp" -ge "$start" && "$tstamp" -le "$stop" ]] && echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: Nice that you have enabled a user friendly time format. :-) Was just about to request that feature.

Comment: I suppose the time stamps in Mr D's example are `17/Dec/2015:04:00:00` and `17/Dec/2015:05:10:09`.

Comment: @Cyrus: the timestamp appears in two formats. I chose the easier to parse

Comment: @Andrea: Thanks for your quick response. But the first part of the log format is the file name which I put here by mistake. As  Cyrus has mentioned my actual problem is the date and time format which is "17/Dec/2015:04:00:00" . So is there any way by which I can parse this time format also.

Comment: @MrD: I edited my answer, but please edit your question too, so that it is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you want to do, using GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[][ ]+"; beg=t2s(beg); end=t2s(end) }
{ cur = t2s($4) }
(cur >= beg) && (cur <= end)

function t2s(time,      t) {
    split(time,t,/[\/:]/)
    t[2]=(match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",t[2])+2)/3
    return mktime(t[3]" "t[2]" "t[1]" "t[4]+0" "t[5]+0" "t[6]+0)
}

$ awk -v beg="17/Dec/2015:04:15" -v end="17/Dec/2015:05:15" -f tst.awk file
access_log.aging.20151217040207:170.37.144.10 - - [17/Dec/2015:05:10:09 -0500] "POST /abc/def/ghi/xyz.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 27 21124 0000FqZTmTG2yuMTJ
```

but it's hard to guess without more sample input and expected output.